# deleting a date and the observations of an xts time series

Tags: r, time-series, xts

I am pretty new to R so I assume I have some beginner questions...

I have my data as an xts time series, but I would look to remove one (or more) dates from the data.  Below is the tail of my data and the class.

What I would like to do is to remove the whole line for [2017-11-16] from the [x] series.  Is there a simple way of doing it?

```
> tail(x)
           CC1.CLOSE CC1.HIGH CC1.LOW CC1.OPEN
2017-11-09      2185     2198    2169     2196
2017-11-10      2212     2226    2179     2186
2017-11-13      2201     2214    2178     2199
2017-11-14      2155     2204    2152     2196
2017-11-15      2129     2162    2110     2155
2017-11-16      2140     2152    2132     2133
> class(x)
[1] "xts" "zoo"
> str(x)
An ‘xts’ object on 2016-01-04/2017-11-16 containing:
  Data: int [1:474, 1:4] 3063 2998 2920 2902 2956 2841 2799 2831 2796 2844 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr [1:4] "CC1.CLOSE" "CC1.HIGH" "CC1.LOW" "CC1.OPEN"
  Indexed by objects of class: [POSIXct,POSIXt] TZ: UTC
  xts Attributes:  
 NULL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to remove the last row you can create a new xts from X like so:

```
x.new <- first(x, (length(MSFT[,1]) - 1))
```

This will remove the last row.

you can also get rid of the index by doing: `coredata(x)` which can sometimes make it easier to manipulate data.

Answer (score 2):

A solution in this case is

```
x["/2017-11-15"]
```

you can look at [this cheat sheet](https://s3.amazonaws.com/assets.datacamp.com/blog_assets/xts_Cheat_Sheet_R.pdf) for more information about `xts` package.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way could be to just use "head"

For example, if you want to remove the last "n" rows from the xts:

```
x1 <- x %>% head(-n)
```